# Why go requires double quoted import declaration

Tags: go

As a go beginner this always gets me whenever I start a new source file. So go's package clause defines the package name, **without** double quotes, since the package name must be an identifier, it cannot contains invalid chars like space or something. However, when it comes to import declarations, the package name must be double quoted, as the package name is exactly the one used in package clause, it must be identifier too(of course / is allowed as separator). It looks to me that would only add more key strokes without other benefits. I wonder why it is designed this way that imports must be double quoted strings.

Also, if we look at other languages, `#include <foo.h>`, `using System.Bar`, `import java.lang.moo` none of them requires imports to be strings.

Comment: [What was the reason behind using quotes in Go's import statements?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/307417/what-was-the-reason-behind-using-quotes-in-gos-import-statements)

Comment: Oh, so it was reserved for the potential of other implementations of the language?

Comment: That appears to be the consensus in that thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A path `a/b/foo` is more like a string than an identifier: identifiers don't have separators, and paths may contain characters that aren't allowed in identifiers. You say package names can't contain spaces, which is true, but paths can, just as package names can't contain periods (`.`), but paths can. For example:

```
import "golang.org/x/exp/shiny/vendor/github.com/BurntSushi/xgb/render"`
```

This is mostly the same as C, which is listed in the question as not using strings to specify `#include` paths, but shares similarities with the go import statement. The two forms are both string-like: `#include <a/b/foo.h>` and `#include "a/b/foo.h"` although one uses `<>` rather than quotes to delimit the string.

Comment: The import path cannot be just arbitrary file system path, because the parts in the path is exactly the identifier defined in package clause. The only char that is not allowed in identifier in the path would be the separator '/'.

Comment: @fluter I'm not sure what you're saying. What do you mean by "the parts in the path is exactly the identifier defined in package clause"? The parts in `golang.org/x/exp/shiny/vendor/github.com/BurntSushi/xgb/render` are `golang.org`, `x`, `exp`, ... `render` and only the latter part (`render`) is the package name, and for example `golang.org` and `github.com` are parts of path but valid identifiers in go.

Comment: You are right, import path is defined as `ImportPath       = string_lit .` in the language spec. Thanks.